# Subquery with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables, items and sales. I want to merge the column 'saledate' which is in sale table, into table items. 
The items table has the columns: saleid, productid, itemsize, quantity, saleprice, saledate. 
The sale table has the columns: saleid, productid, itemsize, quantity, saleprice, saledate.

They both has the same saleid key, and it should be respected in the merge. I tried this code:

```
item['saledate'] = item['saleid'].apply(lambda x : sale['saledate'][sale['saleid'] == x])
```

but it is returning a matrix and not a vector as i expected. This is the image of my tables,

[image]

[image]

and this is what happens when i run the command, 
[image]

Comment: Please show samples of each table, and the expected results. This will help us replicate the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing what your data looks like, it looks like you *intended* your lambda to do this: `lambda x: sale.loc[sale['saleid'] == x, 'saledate']`. However, `pd.merge` is much more appropriate and efficient.

Comment: I didnt worked, it worked just for the first entry. It happened https://imgur.com/a/qvkg0t4.

Answer (score -1):

this is the code, to limit the columns is just use an loc, 
item.set_index('saleid').join(sale.set_index('saleid'))